# How to access a SQLite database in google drive with python?

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api

The goal is to manipulate a SQLite database stored in google drive using jupyter notebook.
I found a way to access the SQLite database in google drive using Google colaboratory, but I don't know how to do it in jupyter notebook.

With the following code, I was able to access google drive, but I cannot connect to the SQLite database.

How can I modify the code in the part "conn = sqlite3.connect(drive_path + db_name)"?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

#####################

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)



import sqlite3

drive_path = "/My Drive/database/"
db_name = "test.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(drive_path + db_name)

cur = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if my solution works for you. As you may have already known, since Sqlite is file-based only, the database file must be in a network shared folder. On my Mac, I mounted my Google drive as a folder in my local drive, and then access my google drive database file as a regular local file:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/local/Google Drive (xxxx@gmail.com)/sample.db')
```

Comment: The size of the file is huge like terrabytes which I cannot have it in local so is there a way I can access it directly in google drive?

Comment: As far as I researched, mounting is the way. Maybe you can check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emEInBmrLs8 to see if it can solve you case. I did not use this tool though.